# How to get file object with ng2-file-upload + angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular-file-upload, ng2-file-upload

I want to accomplish upload on file drag:
I am using ng2-file-upload version 1.2.1 with following code snippet:

app.module.ts:

```
import { FileUploadModule } from 'ng2-file-upload/ng2-file-upload';
..
imports: [
        FileUploadModule
]
```

component.ts:

```
import { FileUploader } from 'ng2-file-upload/ng2-file-upload';

...

class AppXYZComponent{
private uploader: FileUploader = new FileUploader({ url: 'blah.com' });

    public hasBaseDropZoneOver:boolean = false;
    //public hasAnotherDropZoneOver:boolean = false;

    public fileOverBase(e:any):void {
        console.log("hasBaseDropZoneOver", e);
        this.hasBaseDropZoneOver = e;
    }
}
```

app.component.html:

```
<div class="well" ng2FileDrop [uploader]="uploader" [ngClass]="{'another-file-over-class': hasBaseDropZoneOver}"
             (fileOver)="fileOverBase($event)"
             >
            Drop CSV here
        </div>
```

The function fileOverBase gets successfully called on drag, with event e printed as true. Now How can i get the dragged file's object??

Answer (score 6):

You need to use the afterAddingfile method to get the file object in the ng2-file-upload plugin.

```
import { FileUploader } from 'ng2-file-upload/ng2-file-upload';
...

class AppXYZComponent{
public uploader: FileUploader;
public hasBaseDropZoneOver:boolean = false;
//public hasAnotherDropZoneOver:boolean = false;

constructor(){
   this.uploader = new FileUploader({ url: 'blah.com' });
   this.uploader.onAfterAddingFile = (fileItem) => {
                fileItem.withCredentials = false;
                console.log(fileItem); // fileItem is the file object
            };
}
 public fileOverBase(e:any):void {
    console.log("hasBaseDropZoneOver", e);
    this.hasBaseDropZoneOver = e;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I know its late reply but may it will help to others

change app.component.html: with ** code

```
<div class="well" ng2FileDrop [uploader]="uploader" [ngClass]="{'another-file-over-class': hasBaseDropZoneOver}"
         (fileOver)="fileOverBase($event)" **(onFileDrop)="onFileDrop($event)"**
         >
        Drop CSV here
    </div>
```

change component.ts: as below ** code

```
class AppXYZComponent{
private uploader: FileUploader = new FileUploader({ url: 'blah.com' });

public hasBaseDropZoneOver:boolean = false;
//public hasAnotherDropZoneOver:boolean = false;

public fileOverBase(e:any):void {
    console.log("hasBaseDropZoneOver", e);
    this.hasBaseDropZoneOver = e;
}

**public onFileDrop(fileList: File[]) {
    console.log(fileList);// u get file as fileList[0]
}**
}
```